# Find the closed formula for the number of ways to get n dollars using coins of 1, 2 and 5 dollars

Tags: power-series, generating-functions

Ok, this is going to be a long one.

So, using generating functions I have to find a closed formula for the number of ways to get n dollars if I have infinite amounts of coins of 1, 2 and 5 dollars.

This is my procedure:

$(1+x+x^2+...)(1+x^2+x^4+...)(1+x^5+x^{10}+...)$

In this polynomial, the coefficient next to $x^n$ should be the solution to the problem.
First, I convert the 3 factors into formal series

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\times\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(x^2)^n\times\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(x^5)^n$

Now, to multiply those, I need them to be of the format $a_nx^n$ so I split the second and third sum into the following:

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(x^2)^n=\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^n}{2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2})x^n$

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(x^5)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\lfloor{\frac{n}{5}}\rfloor-\lceil{\frac{n}{5}}\rceil)x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1+\lfloor{\frac{n}{5}}\rfloor-\lceil{\frac{n}{5}}\rceil)x^n$

Then I can finally multiply them. I first multiply the first two resulting in

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1+(-1)^{n-k}}{2}x^n$

Then I multiply that with the third sum. The result is the following

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(\sum_{l=0}^{n}\frac{1+(-1)^{n-l}}{2})(1+\lfloor{\frac{n-k}{5}}\rfloor-\lceil{\frac{n-k}{5}}\rceil)x^n$

So, if I'm right, the coefficient next to $x^n$ should be

$a_n=\displaystyle(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1+(-1)^{n-k}}{2})(\sum_{k=0}^{n}(1+\lfloor{\frac{n-k}{5}}\rfloor-\lceil{\frac{n-k}{5}}\rceil))$

So, plugging in $n=3$ works. I get $2$. Either 2 dollar coins, or one two dollars coin.
But when I try $n=5$ I get 6 and I think the result should be 4. What did I do wrong?

Comment: The simplest closed form is probably $\left[\dfrac{(n+4)^2}{20}\right]$ where $[\cdot ]$ is rounding to the nearest integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do this would be to sum each series before you multiply, getting $\frac 1{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^5)}$ and expand that, getting $1+x+2x^2+2x^3+3x^4+4x^5+\dots$  In your case, I believe the upper limit of the $l$ sum should be $k$, not $n$, to get the proper convolution.

Comment: I'd love to use the easier way. How did you get that sum out of that fraction?

Comment: I fed it to [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Expand+1%2F%28%281-x%29%281-x%5E2%29%281-x%5E5%29%29).  I suspect it just multiplied the series you started with term by term, but don't know.